# Remove Answer Your Question button while commenting

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-experience

I hit wrong blue button more than twice for today. It should not be visible while working with comment. Sounds good?

[image: hide this?]

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is strange. I have never had any confusions with having this button not disappear while commenting. It clearly states: "**Answer**, not "comment". If it does really confuse it you, hit <kbd>return</kbd> and never think of those buttons (note this doesn't work when answering, but you don't seem to have similar problems there?).

Comment: Making this comment more constructive for learning more about UX. As a notebook user, the working position of my hand is on touchpad instead of enter, because I may need to scroll window while reviewing comment, or maybe web UI is flaky and I am not sure that I have focus at the right place. So when I finish reviewing, I click the blue stuff automatically. For some reason bottom button is more visible to me, and I am certain that **people don't read buttons every time their click on them**.